# Does the leading eigenvalue of a connected undirected graph always increase with an edge addition?

Tags: graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-graph-theory

Does the leading eigenvalue always increase with an edge addition to the graph? If so, how can I prove this?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried anything yet - devised a potential strategy to check? looked at some examples to see if it holds for them?

Answer (score 1):

It need not increase. Consider for example the graph $G$ formed by taking the  disjoint union of a $k$-regular graph and two isolated vertices $x,y$.

The maximal eigenvalue of $G$  and $G+xy$ is clearly $k$.

If you're looking for ways to tackle this problem I suppose you should look at [Weyl's inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality).

Comment: Are the graphs $G$ and $G+xy$ k-regular?

Comment: No, not necessarily. In fact only if $k = 1$ and $G = K_2$

Comment: Could you please explain why the maximum eigenvalue of $G+xy$ is $k$?

Comment: @M.Badaoui If a graph $G$ has two connected components $H_1$ and $H_2$ then the eigenvalues of $G$ are the eigenvalues of $H_1$ and $H_2$.

Comment: Is the following true? If $G=H_1\cup H_2$, where $H_1$ and $H_2$ are $k$-regular  connected components of $G$. Let $x\in H_1$ and $y\in H_2$. Then the maximal eigenvalue of $G+xy$ is not $k$ since $G+xy$ is not $k$-regular.